# create an array based on a variables string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass a string for an array's name to a function, and the function create that array, e.g:

```
make_array('array_name', data);

function make_array(array_name, data){
    array_name = [];

    // do stuff

    array_name.push(//stuff);

}
```

I don't want to have to create the array first manually

Comment: do you want your array variables injected in global scope? I might sugest you creating a namespace for your arrays. So you can do something like this in your global namespace: var arrayNamespace = {};  and in your function you'll do: arrayNamespace[arrayName] = []; arrayNamespace[arrayName].push(value);

Answer (score 2):

You can do .

```
window[array_name] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval() to do it.

```
eval("var " + array_name + " = []");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the function to return an array, there is no need to create it beforehand. You can just do this:

```
function make_array(data){
    var array_name = [];

    // do stuff

    array_name.push(//stuff);
    return array_name;
}

var my_new_array = make_array(data);
```